DateTime format in maven-openapi-generator-plugin
All fields (LocalDateTime, OffsetDateTime, Date) generated by maven-openapi-generator have @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) annotation. I need to use my custom DateTime format like 2022-01-22T15:33:11.654 +3:00GMT, how can i do this?
I have to use maven-openapi-generator. But i can ignore this field, this field does not act in service logic.
I tried to use spring.mvc.format.date-time property but it have an effect when @DateTimeFormat have no args like iso.
I tried to change maven-openapi-generator configuration but didn't find suitable options in docs. I found  option and set java8 to it, i got OffsetDateTime with time zones but can't use custom format anyway
